# Jquery returning ObjectObject, first two fields return as expected

Tags: php, ajax, forms, jquery

I was wondering if someone could help me out as I *have* googled for quite a while today, and haven't found anything to solve my problem. 
The websites I've looked at mentioned it's because it's returning JSON, but they are getting it on all the fields, not just the one. 
But what I can't understand, is why isn't the first two fields as well? Hence my confusion

I am submitting a login form, using Jquery and AJAX (I'm knew to this).

The first two fields (email and pass) submit, and return as expected.
For testing purposes I simply return their values in `<span id="loginresponse"></span>`.

I have a third field, to prevent CSRF, called 't' (named it random names, to see if this was the problem - I still get [object Object] returned). `<input type="hidden" name="t" value="RandomToken"/>`
When submitting the form, I expect it to return what I entered into the fields - "Email,Pass and RandomToken".
Instead, I get Email,Pass,[Object Object].

Here is my DoLogin function, which is called when the form is submitted.

```
function DoLogin()
    {
        var Email = $("#email").val();
        var Pass = $("#pass").val();
        var LoginResponse = $("#loginresponse");
        var T = $("#t");
        var EmailPlaceholder="Email address";var PassPlaceholder="Your password here";
        $.get('path/to/login_ajax.php?email='+Email+'&pass='+Pass+'&t='+T, function(data)
        {
          $('#loginresponse').html(data);
        });
        /*if(Email != EmailPlaceholder && Pass != PassPlaceholder && Email != "" && Email != " " && Pass !="" && Pass != " ")
        {

        }*/
    }
```

Here is my HTML form:

```
<form action="javascript:DoLogin();" method="post"><!--Also tried changing method to GET, still got the same problem --> 
<input  id="email" class="inputemail" type="text" name="email" size="40" value="Email     address" onclick="$(this).val('');"/><span>Your email</span><br/>
<input id="pass" class="inputpassword" type="password" name="pass" size="40" value="Your password here" onclick="$(this).val('');"/><span>Your password</span><br/>
<input id="t" type="hidden" name="t" value="RandomToken"/>
<input class="indexsubmit" type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
<span id="loginresponse"></span>
```

And finally, login_ajax.php

```
<?php
echo $_GET['email'].$_GET['pass'].$_GET['t'];
?>
```

As mentioned above - I am only echoing the results, for know, as I'm knew to Jquery and AJAX, so I want to check if all fields are returning the values as expected, and one isn't...The token field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are chaining the object `T` of the input element and *not* the element's value to the query string of your GET request.

You should change this line

```
var T = $("#t"); // The object of the input element
```

to this

```
var T = $("#t").val(); // The value of the input element
```

Comment: Thanks Boaz, I knew it'd be something simple that I left out, which I have a tendency of doing. I can't believe I overlooked this, despite scanning through that section of code several times.
I've accepted your answer as you were first and it's explained the reason why my code wasn't working, though I appreciate @Luis, your answer is still valid.

Comment: No problem. It happens to literally *everyone* :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe what you want is:

```
var T = $("#t").val();
```